# Fully differential opamp with weird behavior

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

I have a fully diffrential opamp that is configured like seen in the below picture:

[image]

I have a series of Frequency sweeps (differently scaled input) that I performed and measured with a VNA. The weird part is that it looks so skewed:

[image]

Blue is the expected amplification according to calculations (should def. be true) while the colored dots are the sweeps at different input amplitudes each color.

The OpAmp s configured to amplify approximately 29dB. So according to the Datasheet this should be zero issue up until 100MHz (it's on page 6 of the [ISL55210](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/isl5/isl55210.pdf) DS). Since I sweep only up until 50MHz I am very confused how it results in this broken curve .. It's also not a circuit that's very complicated ...

EDIT: I measure the DUT like seen below, except that there is a 1uF Capacitor in between the adaptor and the VNA to block any DC:

[image]

The input is generated by an [AD8331](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8331_8332_8334.pdf) which works 100% properly as verified in separate measurements. The AD8331 is connected with two 270 Ohm Resistors.

I would be grateful for any hint what I could check ...

P.S. The peak at the beginning is not less strange ...

Comment: Seems you have some 1st order cut-off behavior. I see two RC networks at the output which could be responsible for this. I would also need to know all details of how you apply the input signal and measure at the output. Your VNA probably has 50 ohms inputs ?

Comment: I added the missing information and hope I didn't miss something again ... :)

Comment: "I sweep only up until 30MHz" - So why do your plots go to 50 MHz?

Comment: How did you manage to come up with this impedance mismatched R network?  How did you confirm there is no THD or compression in your results that could result in false fundamental s21 response.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Uhm of course it should be 50 MHz ...

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 how do you mean mismatched? Like that the amp sees 250 Ohms and the VNA sees 50 Ohms, so everything sees what it expects.Well I actually did not verify there is no THD, I just assumed it since through all frequencies the amplification is constant +- statistical error. Well about compression: I mean isn't that one effect that could be responsibe for my plots? So idk but isn't that exactly what I asked about? :S Or are you talking about the AD8331 measurements?

Comment: I do not overload the amp, if you mean that. I can see the picture perfect sinewave that i feed in come out again at the oscilloscope if I terminate it with 50 Ohms.

Comment: @Yatekii  The VNA sees 28 Ω//(237+250)Ω =22.8 Ω not 50 Ω . Probe the output under this load for distortion not just with a 50 Ω termination your termination is 250 Ω on the unmonitored side and DUT to VNA while DUT output load is 237+28//50 Ω =255 Ω

Comment: @Yatekii You can see the % distortion by the asymmetry of the sine +pk and -pk % difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are expecting without using input resistors. At the moment you have a differential trans impedance amplifier and that will have virtually zero ohms input impedance. The AD8331 is a voltage output device so something looks very screwed up in your interfacing philosophy.

Try using input resistors in series with each input line and look at what the VGA output of the AD8331 is expecting to see - fig 57.

Comment: Hey! As mentioned: The AD8331 is connected with two 270 Ohm Resistors. :) This is not exactly 250 Ohms as expected but should work. Maybe you have overlooked that, maybe I have misunderstood your comment, then, sorry for that.

Comment: It would be so much better if you drew a complete circuit than bits of circuit. So you are saying the AD8331 connects to IN2+ and IN2- with 270 ohm resistors. Also, can you properly explain the multi-coloured spectral graphs and what the different colours represent?